# Drop the smallest value from pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series, drop

I have a pandas.Series:

```
Name: vector, dtype: float64
1     74.67
2     87.78
3     97.00
```

I want to drop the smallest value from Series. I managed to do:

```
vector = vector[vector != vector.min()]
```

But what if my Series has got somewhat identical the smallest values like this:

```
Name: vector, dtype: float64
1     74.67
2     87.78
3     74.67
```

I would like to drop only one values and leave another one and get Series:

```
Name: vector, dtype: float64
2     87.78
3     74.67
```

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `idxmin()` to get index of the **first** smallest value and drop:

```
s.drop(s.idxmin())
```

Answer (score 1):

Get index of first minimal value by [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and then drop by [`Series.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html):

```
vector = vector.drop(vector.idxmin())
print (vector)
2    87.78
3    97.00
Name: vector, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
s=s.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1:]
```